# Adding two polar forms?

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to figure out how this polar form was added? please see the picture below and try to explain step by step because my math is bad...

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ63K.png)

Comment: Can you please reveal us more from the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert both the numbers into complex or rectangular forms. ($j$ is generally used instead of $i$ as $i$ is used for current in Physics and Electronics, if you're related to these)

> $46.188\angle{-36.87^o} = 36.950-27.713i$
>   $12.29\angle{94.79^o}=-1.026+12.247i$

Add both and convert the sum back into polar form

> $36.950-27.713i + (-1.026+12.247i) = 35.924-15.466i = 39.111\angle{-23.29}$

Comment: Thank you so much I will remember this method.

Comment: You're welcome, and I hope you use Scientific Calculator , otherwise it becomes tedious to calculate